# Android HttpClient memory leak?

Tags: android, httpclient

I was looking at code for a sample Android application. Within the code, the application creates an HttpClient, but I never see anywhere where the connection is closed. So I was wondering does this code create a memory leak? If not, can you explain why?

The link to the sample code is at: 
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/src/com/example/android/samplesync/client/NetworkUtilities.html

Comment: show your code and error log.

Comment: Why do you think an HttpClient needs to be closed? Is there any documentation that says so? Notice that the httpclient is created once and kept in a static variable.

Comment: @aromero From what I learned, usually when you create a connection you should close it if it's not being used or else it could be creating memory leaks.

Comment: @user370305 - I think Hank is asking why there is _not_ an error. Looking at the error log isn't going to help. Also, it's a stock sample project; there's no need to post the code here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HttpClient relies on a ClientConnectionManager to handle opening and closing connections. It (HttpClient) is a utility class that is *supposed* to allow you to forget about lots of details like closing connections.

*"That's not a bug. It's a feature!"*